# Why is Riot JS evaluating this as javascript

Tags: riot.js

I have a basic button tag I am experimenting with and I'm unsure why Riot JS is not rendering the below.

If I wrap "Login" in a `<span>` tag it renders correctly.

I expect that because I have defined my `<script>` within my custom riot tag, then it would evaluate it as HTML. Instead I get `Login is not defined` error in my browser.

Is there a way I have to escape this text if I want it to render as HTML, or am I missing something?

```
<login-button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent">

  Login

  <script type="coffee">

    @hello = 'world'

  </script>

</login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result you can use a `<yield/>` tag within your custom tag.

```
<login-button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent">

  <yield/>

  <script type="coffee">

    @hello = 'world'

  </script>

</login-button>
```

Then where you are calling the tag, add your desired text ie:

```
<login-button>
  Login Button Text
</login-button>
```

Reference: http://riotjs.com/api/#a-nameyielda-yielding-nested-html